# Why did this PC power supply stop functioning?

Tags: power-supply, security

I have an old PC power supply which I want to use because it outputs 12V and 5V very nicely. 12V is the yellow wire (this is all labelled on the power supply itself), 5V is the red wire and ground is the black wire. The on/off switch for the power supply is the green one.

Following information I found online in various places, I connected the green and black wires to make the power supply function.

Since I only wanted a 12V and 5V supply for my project, I wanted to tidy up the other cables by cutting them. However, I didn't want to leave live wires hanging out so I put all of the yellow wires together and taped them. I did the same with the other coloured wires.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I thought since the wires are already floating, cutting the cables and tying them together (the ones with the same voltage) would not do anything bad.

What happens now is that once I switch it on, the fan runs for a second and comes to a halt; I have the suspicion that I've triggered some sort of fail safe, but I'm not sure how.

What did I do wrong? Is this power supply still good?

Comment: *" I connected the green and black wires to make the power supply function"*. Did you keep them connected or you just touch the two wires together to switch on the device?

Comment: Keep them connected. I have it soldered to an on/off switch.

Comment: Did you include a dummy load in the power supply?

Comment: I just did the exact same thing with another power supply, one by A Open Solutions, and it works perfectly....

Comment: What do you mean a dummy load? I'm unfamiliar with the concept.

Comment: Most power supplies require a load ("dummy load") across one or more of the outputs to operate

Comment: Before I cut the wires, the supply functioned perfectly (the fan was running). So, could it be that this one doesn't???

Comment: Typical ATX supplies like this require > 5W load on the 5V line to properly regulate. So Put something like a large 10Ohm or 5Ohm resistor on the 5V line to GND.

Comment: Just to be sure: you actually electrically connected together all of the wires of a given color? The reason is some of these wires are actually voltage sense wires so the supply can compensate for voltage drop in the wires. (The sense wires are typically smaller guage.) if you left a sense wire floating, the supply may not function correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this guide](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-make-a-bench-power-supply-from-an-old-atx-psu/), specifically the part at the end "Lastly, the fake load".

Make sure you use a proper load resistor. I've seen other guides (which I now can't find!) that say to file off the coating on the inside of the case where the vent is and mount the resistor there with thermal paste and cable ties.

Edit:
I found the other [article](http://web2.murraystate.edu/andy.batts/ps/powersupply.htm) with discussion of load resistor.

Answer (score 0):

Some power supplies have multiple 12V supplies on them. If that's the case here, you might have shorted them together. Is there a label giving the current specs for the individual supplies? If so, that will tell you how many 12V supplies there are.

Comment: The label is the one I posted a picture of. I only grouped the wires which were the same colour and I didn't attach expose them, I just electrically taped them together.

Comment: Label shows only single 12V rail. Your good OP.

Comment: Argh, I'm blind. Yeah, it's right there. Sorry.